# Redis zslGetElementByRank(t_zset.c) return error address

Tags: redis, skip-lists

When i debugging Redis SkipList, I wanna use zslGetElementByRank(t_zset.c).  I replaced Redis main function code as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    zskiplistNode *node;

    zskiplist *zsl = zslCreate();           //create a skiplist

    zslInsert(zsl, 65.5, sdsnew("tom"));  //insert some data
    zslInsert(zsl, 87.5, sdsnew("jack"));
    zslInsert(zsl, 70.0, sdsnew("alice"));
    zslInsert(zsl, 95.0, sdsnew("tony"));

    printf("The Rank equal 4 is :");         
    node = zslGetElementByRank(zsl, 4);       //get element by rank
    printf("%s->%f\n", node->ele, node->score); 

    return 0;
}
```

$ make
$ ./src/redis-server
[1]    29749 segmentation fault  ./src/redis-server              // i get a segmentfault

then , i debug the code, i print the address in zslGetElementByRank and main , the address is:

(gdb) p x     `x is zslGetElementByRank returnd`
$1 = (zskiplistNode *) 0x7ffff6e25000
(gdb) p node
$2 = (zskiplistNode *) 0xfffffffff6e25000

why the address changed from 0x7ffff6e25000 to 0xfffffffff6e25000, I am confused.

Sorry to forget it，My Redis Version is 4.0.1

Thanks!

Comment: I recompile the code with glibc malloc :           
$ make MALLOC=libc  
$./src/redis-server   
The Rank equal 4 is :tony->95.000000  

the answer is right, but i don't the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer , just because i don't declare zslGetElementByRank in server.c .
the warning is :
 `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`